# Pivotal Tracker API File Upload

Tags: php, api, curl, file-upload, pivotaltracker

I've got this form to upload a file. I want it to be uploaded as a comment in Pivotal Tracker with the API. What will I write in the code? I'm new to Curl.

**Edit:** In Pivotal Tracker you can upload file .jpg, .xls, etc in the comments, and it creates an downloadable icon/thumbnail.

Comments Doc: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5#projects_project_id_stories_story_id_comments_post

File attachment Doc:
https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5#file_attachment_resource

**upload.html:**

```
<form action="pt.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="file" name="pt_xls" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**pt.php:**

```
$response = pivotalTracker("https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/XXXXXXXX/stories/XXXXXXXX/comments");

$resArr = array();
$resArr = json_decode($response);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo "</pre>";

function pivotalTracker($url) {


    $pivotalAPIToken = 'XXXXXXXXXX'; 
    $curlHeader = array("X-TrackerToken: ".$pivotalAPIToken, "Content-type: application/json");

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $curlHeader,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $content  = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: You should specify what you want as the comment. Is it something within the file? If so, you will need something to read the xls file since it is encoded with Microsoft sauce.

Comment: In Pivotal Tracker you can upload file .jpg, .xls, etc in the comments, and it creates an downloadable icon/thumbnail.

Comments: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5#projects_project_id_stories_story_id_comments_post

File attachment: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/v5#file_attachment_resource

Comment: According to the links you provided you need to upload the file separately. When you upload a file, you get an attachment object back. When you create a new comment, you need to attach that object to the data you want to send.

Comment: Thanks!
What if I upload the file to my server, then I send it over via Curl, and then I delete it on my server. How will the $data array in my script look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the right way, but it works!

**file_in.php**

```
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
          $errors= array();
          $theFile = $_FILES['file'];
          $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
          $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
          $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pt_uploads/".$file_name);

       }

        $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pt_uploads/".$file_name;
        $response = pivotalTracker("https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/*ID*/uploads", $file_name, $target_file, $file_type);


        function pivotalTracker($url, $file_name, $target_file, $file_type) {

            $pivotalAPIToken = 'XXXXXXXX';
            $curlHeader = array("X-TrackerToken: ".$pivotalAPIToken, "Content-type: multipart/form-data", "Content-Disposition: form-data;'");


            $cfile = curl_file_create('../pt_uploads/'.$file_name,$file_type,$file_name);

            $data = array('file' => $cfile);

            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $curlHeader,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  
                CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
            ); 

            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

            $content  = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            unlink($target_file);

            $resArr = array();
            $resArr = json_decode($content);
            $theId = $resArr->id;
            $theName = $resArr->filename;


            header('Location: pt_file_comment.php?pt_file_id='.$theId.'&filename='.$theName);

    }
```

**pt_file_comment.php**

```
$pt_file_id = $_GET['pt_file_id'];
    $pt_file_name = $_GET['filename'];

    $response = pivotalTracker("https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/*ID*/stories/*ID*/comments", $pt_file_id, $pt_file_name);
    $resArr = array();
    $resArr = json_decode($response);

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo "</pre>";

    function pivotalTracker($url, $pt_file_id, $pt_file_name) {

    $file_data[] = array('id' => $pt_file_id,);
    $fileObject = (object) $file_data;


        $data = array(
            'text'              =>    'file_attachments/'.$pt_file_id.'/'.$pt_file_name,
            'file_attachments'  => $file_data,
        );

        $pivotalAPIToken = 'XXXX';
        $curlHeader = array("X-TrackerToken: ".$pivotalAPIToken, "Content-type: application/json");

        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $curlHeader,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        ); 

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        $content  = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $content;
    }
```